# How to Increment consistently in Neo4j, Cypher is too slow?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Im currently using Neo4j 2.0+ and cypher to create and save sessions.

My project at times requires multiple writes per second to a node labeled 'ChildSession', and I notice that when I 'increment' the ChildSession_ID in cypher, I often have ChildSession_ID's skipping numbers or being the same number.

Not sure if neo4j/cypher is too slow for my requirements, but I doubt it since the internal Neo4j Node ID's are incremented normally.

```
The cypher command i'm using, to increment ChildSession is:

 match (p:ChildSession) with count(p) as Total 
 Create (b:ChildSession{ChildSession_ID:Total + 1 })
```

One would expect the ChildSession_ID to increment, but I get the following results, when I check the nodes in neo4j browser:

```
match (u:ChildSession) return u,ID(u)

Results:
ChildSession_ID 1
44997
ChildSession_ID 1
44998
ChildSession_ID 1
44999
ChildSession_ID 4
45000
ChildSession_ID 5
45001
ChildSession_ID 6
45002
ChildSession_ID 6
45003
ChildSession_ID 8
45004
ChildSession_ID 8
45005
```

I've been unable to get neo4j to increment accurately.
I tried using redis and its hincrby command which increments and then put this variable into my cypher query's ChildSession_ID attribute. This method works, but I would rather do it with cypher instead.

The argument could be made to use redis only instead for fast writes, but I use a hiearchy of session levels and need the querying neo4j offers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you added any manual locking around access to the ChildSession label? I would expect otherwise that the `MATCH` statement could happen on multiple threads at the same time (no read locking). The result of this would be the same value for `Total` being passed to your `CREATE` statement.

Two things spring to mind, using the COUNT is maybe not the fastest and would not guarantee unique values if you were ever to delete a ChildSession (maybe you do not care?). Maintaining the count as a property is probably faster (query time) and incurs minimal overhead.

I believe that the correct way to achieve this is to use a MERGE statement on a separate label which should lock on the `Incremental` Node through the whole transaction (as described in [this Blog Post](http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?8012859)):

```
MERGE (nid:Incremental{type:ChildSession})
ON CREATE SET nid.count = 1
ON MATCH SET nid.count = nid.count + 1
RETURN nid.count
```

Caveat: Whilst I believe this is the correct way to do it, I'll be damned if it is working nicely in a rapid async environment, suggesting that the semantics of the locking are not what I expect.

You could of course generate a UUID if the incremental nature of your ChildSession_ID is not important?

Comment: Although the incremental works at normal speed it doesn't increment as expected when adding multiple nodes per second as i'm doing.
May be neo4j issue, but I am taking the UUID approach.
I was able to accomplish the increments by using redis's hincrby command. Thanks +1